# Owl-Carousel not working! Beginner web developer

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I want to recreate the carousel just above the "browse all courses" button on this website https://www.bringyourownlaptop.com/

***I wanted to make this post as straight to the point as possible, but it seems like stackoverflow is forcing me to type more stuff so I'll give you guys more details. If you want to save time, just skip reading the entire next section.***

**DETAILS:**

1. Expected result:

Multiple cards on a row with "<" and ">" controls on the side that allow the user to navigate through the cards. After intensively researching on google and youtube, I found the "owlcarousel" plugin or whatever that seemed to work for me. So I tried to recreate this carousel: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/basic.html and I'd reposition the controls as I want afterwards.

2. Actual result:

There's no carousel whatsoever, if I add more cards or change the display size they all shrink in order to fit within their container (I've tried using "flex-wrap" but it doesn't change anything).

3. What I've tried:

Adding autoplay, autoplayTimeout, etc... from different similar questions here on stackoverflow and other websites...

I believe the problem is how/where I imported the css, js, etc. but I've tried putting it on the head, footer, everything really and it doesn't work.

Here's my entire code:

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.wrapper-grid {
    display: grid;
    height: 100%;
    place-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    background: #272727;
}

.slider {
    /* max-width: 1000px; */
    /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.card {
    border-color: #272727;
    flex: 1;
}

.card-img-top {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #471A69;
}

.card-img-top img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.card-body {
    background: #7A2DB5;
}

.card-body p {
    text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="carousel.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="owlcarousel/owl.theme.default.min.css">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="wrapper-grid">
        <div class="slider d-flex owl-carousel">
            <div class="card mx-2">
                <img src="./Exports_iOS/Icon awesome-adobe.svg" class="card-img-top py-3 px-3" alt="Adobe">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Suite Adobe</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Aliquid, iusto. Quas
                        corporis animi voluptas facilis minus? Laudantium veritatis debitis tenetur.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mx-2">
                <img src="./Exports_iOS/Icon awesome-bootstrap.svg" class="card-img-top py-3 px-3" alt="Bootsrap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Bootstrap</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Aliquid, iusto. Quas
                        corporis animi voluptas facilis minus? Laudantium veritatis debitis tenetur.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mx-2">
                <img src="./Exports_iOS/Icon awesome-php.svg" class="card-img-top py-3 px-3" alt="PHP">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">PHP</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Aliquid, iusto. Quas
                        corporis animi voluptas facilis minus? Laudantium veritatis debitis tenetur.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mx-2">
                <img src="./Exports_iOS/Icon awesome-python.svg" class="card-img-top py-3 px-3" alt="Python">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Python</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Aliquid, iusto. Quas
                        corporis animi voluptas facilis minus? Laudantium veritatis debitis tenetur.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mx-2">
                <img src="./Exports_iOS/Icon awesome-wordpress.svg" class="card-img-top py-3 px-3" alt="Wordpress">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Wordpress</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Aliquid, iusto. Quas
                        corporis animi voluptas facilis minus? Laudantium veritatis debitis tenetur.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mx-2">
                <img src="./Exports_iOS/Icon ionic-logo-javascript.svg" class="card-img-top py-3 px-3" alt="Javascript">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Javascript</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Aliquid, iusto. Quas
                        corporis animi voluptas facilis minus? Laudantium veritatis debitis tenetur.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var owl = $('.owl-carousel');    
        $(document).ready(function () {
            owl.owlCarousel({
                items: 3,
                loop: true,
                margin: 10,
                autoplay: true,
                autoplayTimeout: 1000,
                autoplayHoverPause: true
            });
            $('.play').on('click', function () {
                owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay', [1000])
            })
            $('.stop').on('click', function () {
                owl.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay')
            })
        });
    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Make sure to include ```jQuery``` library to your page, loaded before the owl script.

Comment: @prettyInPink isn't it correct already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be working for me.
Are you really sure that you are loading jquery correctly?
Are you seeing errors in the console?

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.wrapper-grid {
    display: grid;
    height: 100%;
    place-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    background: #272727;
}

.slider {
    /* max-width: 1000px; */
    /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.card {
    border-color: #272727;
    flex: 1;
}

.card-img-top {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #471A69;
}

.card-img-top img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.card-body {
    background: #7A2DB5;
}

.card-body p {
    text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" integrity="sha512-tS3S5qG0BlhnQROyJXvNjeEM4UpMXHrQfTGmbQ1gKmelCxlSEBUaxhRBj/EFTzpbP4RVSrpEikbmdJobCvhE3g==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="wrapper-grid">
        <div class="slider d-flex owl-carousel">
            <div class="card mx-2">
                <img src="./Exports_iOS/Icon awesome-adobe.svg" class="card-img-top py-3 px-3" alt="Adobe">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Suite Adobe</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Aliquid, iusto. Quas
                        corporis animi voluptas facilis minus? Laudantium veritatis debitis tenetur.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mx-2">
                <img src="./Exports_iOS/Icon awesome-bootstrap.svg" class="card-img-top py-3 px-3" alt="Bootsrap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Bootstrap</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Aliquid, iusto. Quas
                        corporis animi voluptas facilis minus? Laudantium veritatis debitis tenetur.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mx-2">
                <img src="./Exports_iOS/Icon awesome-php.svg" class="card-img-top py-3 px-3" alt="PHP">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">PHP</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Aliquid, iusto. Quas
                        corporis animi voluptas facilis minus? Laudantium veritatis debitis tenetur.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mx-2">
                <img src="./Exports_iOS/Icon awesome-python.svg" class="card-img-top py-3 px-3" alt="Python">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Python</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Aliquid, iusto. Quas
                        corporis animi voluptas facilis minus? Laudantium veritatis debitis tenetur.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mx-2">
                <img src="./Exports_iOS/Icon awesome-wordpress.svg" class="card-img-top py-3 px-3" alt="Wordpress">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Wordpress</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Aliquid, iusto. Quas
                        corporis animi voluptas facilis minus? Laudantium veritatis debitis tenetur.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mx-2">
                <img src="./Exports_iOS/Icon ionic-logo-javascript.svg" class="card-img-top py-3 px-3" alt="Javascript">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Javascript</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Aliquid, iusto. Quas
                        corporis animi voluptas facilis minus? Laudantium veritatis debitis tenetur.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

    <script>
           
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var owl = $('.owl-carousel'); 
            owl.owlCarousel({
                items: 3,
                loop: true,
                margin: 10,
                autoplay: true,
                autoplayTimeout: 1000,
                autoplayHoverPause: true
            });
            $('.play').on('click', function () {
                owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay', [1000])
            })
            $('.stop').on('click', function () {
                owl.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay')
            })
        });
    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you copied-pasted my code and it is working for you then idk where the problem could be... could my pc interfere in this?

Comment: ahh it's working now! Thank you so much :) what was the problem? So I can prevent it from happening again

Comment: It's difficult to say, because you are loading the files from your server, so I have no idea where you could have linked them wrong or other. Glad it is working, consider accepting the answer. Thanks ;)

Comment: Accepted the answer thanks! Now I'm having a bit of trouble with making it responsive but I'll keep trying for a while but if I can't solve it I'll ask for help again :(

Comment: You just need to add it in your options: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/responsive.html

Comment: Yes, I did it but I had to add the class "item" to the cards in order for it to work. Solved this problem :) ! Now I got another one unfortunately! I will make a new discussion if I can't solve it because it's probably a glitch/bug: when I resize the window with the inspector, it messes everything up and I have to press F5 in order for the cards carousel to adjust correctly.